# Происхождение слова "варвар" — трактовка учебника истории

Tags: этимология

Хорошо помню, что, когда мы изучали историю Древнего мира, в учебнике было написано, что слово "варвар" придумали римляне, потому что им казалось, что западные племена говорят тарабарщину "вар-вар-вар". Уже тогда, в пятом классе, эта версия показалась мне дурацкой. По-моему, слово "варвар" происходит от латинского barba — "борода" (в Древнем Риме окладистых бород не носили).
Кто прав?

Comment: В Древнем Риме носили бороды. Как раз в период упадка империи и близкого "знакомства" с варварами.

В целом я не вижу причин ставить под сомнение версию Фасмера.

Comment: В Древнем Риме носили совершенно другие бороды - короткие и ухоженные. Читайте внимательно вопрос: "ОКЛАДИСТЫХ бород не носили".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Древнерусское – варваръ.
Старославянское – варъваръ.
Греческое – barbaros.
Латинское – barbarus (чужестранец).
Существительное «варвар» пришло в русский язык из греческого языка позднего периода в XI в. Производные от него слова стали появляться с первой половины XVIII в.
Во всех языках, кроме русского, украинского, белорусского и болгарского, слово произносится и пишется с начальным «б» («b»), а не «в» («v»). Это можно объяснить тем, что слово было заимствовано непосредственно из позднегреческого, а не из латинского, как это было во французском, немецком и английском.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему Ваш ответ выбран в качестве верного. На вопрос Вы не ответили ни на йоту.

Answer (score 2):

Фасмер говорит так:

> Происходит от др.-греч. βάρβαρος
> «негреческий, иноземный; варвар»,
> далее, по-видимому, звукоподражат.. В
> ряде европейских языков слово заимств.
> через лат. barbarus.Русск. варвар —
> через др.-русск., ст.-слав., варваръ,
> варъваръ (заимств. из греч.).

Так что версия учебника очень схожа с этимологией, предлагаемой авторитетным источником.

Answer (score 0):

Friedrich I Barbarossa- король Германии и император Священной Римской империи - больше подходит и под греческое barbaros, и под латинское(римское!) barbarus и написанием, и произношением, да и облико ***а***морале соответствует.
Очень многие современные слова получились от искажения при произношении, напр. aqua vita - whisky - даже ни одной буквы не совпадает, однако это никто не оспаривает. Я бы связал слово варвар со словами warrior, warfare. Связь русских и английских слов очень хорошо прослеживается на различных примерах. Имею ввиду - старые русские слова. Различающиеся при написании, а, тем более, при особенностях национального произношения слова некоторых языков очень схожи. 
          Напр., почему Deutschland - Германия по русски и по английски, французы и испанцы стесняются назвать гер-guerre-война, называя "алемания" -Allemagne, alemania, а на родственном испанскому и французскому итальянском - та же германия-germania?

Comment: Уишке (вода по-ирландски) поздней переделалось в виски: https://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=wT#ru/ga/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0 То есть, практически калька с русской или польской водки, тоже имеющей этимологию из воды. :)
 11 янв '15 в 18:16

Aleksandr Viktorovic Barybin

Answer (score 0):

Если в мирном городе появился иностранец, то впечатление о нём в народе останется, я думаю,  в первую очередь неспособностью к общению, или каким-то особым словам или звукам речи.
 Другое дело, когда под стенами из леса появляется полчище вооруженных немытых, нестриженых людей. С намерением, далеким от того, чтобы что-то там продать или купить. А когда их сверху спрашивают, мол: "Что изволите?", те в ответ орут: "War! War!" - и пускают горящие стрелы, это производит впечатление.

Comment: У вас есть научное подтверждение столь оригинальной версии?

Answer (score 0):

У беллетриста Алексеева, в цикле романов "Валькирия" и т.д. есть место, где главный герой встречается с филологом, который специализируется на древне-арийском языке. Так вот согласно Алексееву (в книге, кстати, идет отсылка к Гумилеву), АР с древне-арийского - это земля. РА- это солнце. Таким образом получаем боевой клич древних ариев: ВАР-ВАР, что надо понимать как " В ЗЕМЛЮ-В ЗЕМЛЮ" А победный клич: У-РА!, соответственно - "У-СОЛНЦА"

Comment: Очередной восторженный поклонник псевдолингвистических теорий Задорнова.

Comment: В чужой монастырь со своим LEGO.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше мнение правильно. Изначально слово "варвар" (от латинского barba — "борода") означало просто "бородач". Но в Древнем Риме свободные граждане бород не носили, дабы вшей не разводить они ввели бритьё бороды. Поэтому бородатый человек на улицах Древнего Рима — это или раб (то есть грязный, немытый, невежественный), или иностранец (чужеземец). Вот отсюда и пошли нынешние смыслы этого слова.

Answer (score 0):

ВАРВАР — слово греческого происхождения, попавшее в латинский.
В греческом языке нет "В", поэтому это слово звучит как "барбар".
После этого можно строить гипотезы.

Comment: *В греческом языке нет "В", поэтому это слово звучит как "барбар".* - поясните, пожалуйста, где звучит - и кто куда попал.

Answer (score -1):

Пользователь **Fuchoin Kazuki** пишет: 
« Хорошо помню, что, когда мы изучали историю Древнего мира, в учебнике было написано, что слово "варвар" придумали римляне, потому что им казалось, что западные племена говорят тарабарщину "вар-вар-вар". Уже тогда, в пятом классе, эта версия показалась мне дурацкой. По-моему, слово "варвар" происходит от латинского barba — "борода" (в Древнем Риме окладистых бород не носили). »

Я уверен, что в Учебнике все написано верно.
Что римляне, что греки, в силу их темпераментности..., часто соприкасались с другими народами, и первое, что им мешало - это, естественно, незнание, непонимание чужого языка; тогда не было всевозможных словарей, как сейчас.
Эту ситуацию они характеризовали как общение с бар-бар, т.е. с людьми, непонятно что за лепет производящими.
Русское слово "бормотать" семантически близко к значению слова(греко-латинского) "бар-бар".

Далее, вот в осетинском, как индоевропейском языке, есть это же слово, и оно имеет только одно значение - ПРОИЗНОСИТЬ что-то непонятно, нескладно, невнятно, неправильно и т.д.: 
"бæр-бæр кæнын"  (здесь "кæнын" делать, мочь, производить)
  ударение, в т.ч. фразовое, на второй букве "æ". Фраза подразумевает пренебрежение. Звук "æ" - это звуки "а/о" в русских словах в неударном слоге(например, парта=партæ, полёт=пæлёт). В отличие от русского, в осетинском звук "æ" часто под ударением.

ВЫШЕПРИВЕДЕННАЯ ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ СЛОВА **"бар-бар"** КРИСТАЛЬНО ЕСТЕСТВЕННО.  ВСЁ ЖЕ ДРУГОЕ ВОСПРИНИМАЕТСЯ КАК КОНТАМИНАЦИЯ С МНОГОЧИСЛЕННЫМИ СОЗВУЧНЫМИ СЛОВАМИ В РАЗНЫХ ЯЗЫКАХ (war, борода, и т.д.)

Comment: Для начала - вопрос. Зачем заглавная в слове "учебник"?  Про то, какое отношение осетинский имеет к древнему Риму - это уже дополнительный вопрос.  На все остальное прошу представить аргументацию. Более серьезную, чем игра на случайных созвучиях и утверждения "я уверен".

Comment: "Учебник" - так я написал для абстрактного слова "учебник". Этим я подчеркиваю, что я имею в виду конкретно данный учебник (неужто это неясно ?!).

Comment: Т.е. сознательно нарушили правила русского языка? Чтобы придать солидности своим доводам?

Comment: Уваж. **бегемотус,** я ничего не нарушал. Для исключения двусмысленности можно выделить слово в той или иной манере, и написание существительного с большой буквы - одна из них (т.е. речь о конкретном объекте данного класса). Что же до древнего Рима и греков, то исторически засвидетельствованные  контакты греков, римлян и ираноязычных скифов, сармат, алан (предки осетин) способствовали восприятию ряда слов друг у друга.

Comment: Два года прошло однако. Но смысла вы не добавили. Чтобы не затягивать бесполезные "дискуссии". "Учебник" извольте писать со строчной буквы, поскольку иное не соответвует правилам русского языка. Ваши аргументация о возможной связи слова варвар с "аланами" никакой критики не выдерживает. Собственно, и аргументации-то как таковой нету.

Answer (score -1):

История всегда менялась писарями, которые что-то не понимали, много-чего уже поменялось, но предположение Варвар - бородач, чужеземец, я тоже считаю верным. Римляне действительно не носили бород, а варвары действительно были в основном воинами и жили в походных условиях, борода их согревала и защищала как от холода, так и от ветра и т.д. Современные люди насмотрелись американских фильмов, и увидев Арнольда без бороды, сразу склоняются к другой версии понятия данного слова.

Comment: Современные люди насмотрелись американских фильмов и считают, что римляне греков за людей не считали, ведь те бороды носили. Хотя о чём я говорю, слово "варвар" ведь изначально греческое, а лишь позднее оно пришло в латинский язык.